# connect to svn using proxy

Tags: svn, version-control

Can anyone tell me how can I make my SVN(TurtoiseSVN) to use the proxy? I'm using windows XP, I've seen bunch of similar questions on this matter and none of them says where(in which location) should I change my configuration. Does anybody know that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]

Answer (score 0):

Right click in Windows explorer -> TortoiseSVN -> Settings

Choose the Network "tab" and tune your proxy there